# Haskell — Get multiple values from infinite list without starting the list over

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm currently working on an implementation of [Project Euler problem 40](https://projecteuler.net/problem=40) and am trying to figure out how to take multiple items from a list in Haskell without starting the list over.

Currently, I have a list `champernowne` of type `Integral a => [a]` which will return an infinite list of the digits of Champernowne's constant, then I take the first, tenth, etc. terms off of this sequence and multiply them to get the answer. The actual code for this is:

```
ans = (product . map (champernowne !!)) [0, 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999]
```

The problem with this implementation is (I'm assuming) that Haskell will go through the list from the beginning of the sequence each time that it wants to get a new term. How can I make it so that haskell only goes through the sequence from elements 1 to 1 000 000 and then pulls the terms out of the middle? I've already tried scanl in hope that the lazy evaluation would aid me, but it did not:

```
ans = (product . head . scanl (flip drop) champernowne) [10, 90, 900, 9000, 90000]
```

Just to clarify, the first bit of code *does* work, but I'm trying to improve my implementation to be a bit more efficient.

Comment: snd $ unzip $ filter (\\(i, _) -> i \`elem\` [10, 90, 900, 900, 9000]) $ zip [1..10000000] champernowne

Comment: @EarlGray Could you explain that one-liner? It seems to run a lot slower than the original, despite yielding the correct answer.

Comment: `zip` produces a lazy list of pairs [(1, champ!!0), (2, champ!!1), ... , (10000000, champ!!999999)]. This list is then funneled through filter: is the first item of a tuple one in the list `[10, 90, 900, 9000, whatever]`. The filtered result is run through unzip, which gives back `([<indeces>], [<filtered values>])`. Then `snd` takes `[<filtered values>]` only.

Comment: In my oneliner the list `champernowne` is generated only once, so if your solution is faster, you don't have to worry about its performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The efficient method to solve that problem is to compute the digits without constructing the list.

But if your desired indices are given in ascending order, you can get that without starting from the fron for each by computing the relative offsets and `drop`ping the appropriate number of items to reach the next desired index

```
-- supposes the list of indices in ascending order
indices :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
indices xs is = go xs offsets
  where
    offsets = zipWith (-) is (0:is)
    go ys (k:ks) = case drop k ys of
                     z:zs -> z : go (z:zs) ks
                     _    -> []
    go _ [] = []
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll look into how I've structured my list implementation and see if I can make it a bit more efficient.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "drop (k-1) ys", with a special case for the first offset (maybe zipping "(-1):is")?

Comment: @ItaiZukerman Not here, I allowed for repeated indices, thus put the selected element back into the list that is the dropped from. It would be `drop (k-1)` if the selected element wasn't put back, which is probably the more common case.

Answer (score 1):

you just have a slight error in your second expression: use `map head` instead of `head` there.

```
map (list !!) xs   -- [0, 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999] ==

map head . tail . scanl (flip drop) list $ zipWith (-) xs (0:xs)
                   -- [9, 90, 900, 9000, 90000]
```